# How to echo bloginfo about the template directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently coding for a wordpress theme and are creating specific pages, one function that i wanted to do is that if there's an existing cookie, it echoes a menu while without an existing cookie, it echoes something else.

One problem that I encounter is with the echo function, the `bloginfo('template_directory')` doesn't work in my script.

Here's an overview

```
echo '<a href="'.bloginfo('template_directory').'/logout.php" class="linkit">LOGOUT</a>
                    <div class="para">Temporary giving up super power.</div>';
```

I tried blackslashing it and it only gave me a more confusing link with the whole `bloginfo('template_directory')` in it. e.g. `www.yoursite.com/bloginfo('template_directory')/logout.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_bloginfo()` to put the info in a variable.

```
$templateDirectory= get_bloginfo('template_directory');
echo '<a href="'.$templateDirectory.'/logout.php" class="linkit">LOGOUT</a><div class="para">Temporary giving up super power.</div>';
```

Comment: Just beat me to it :)

Comment: Sorry m8, next one is for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the function [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), as suggested in [Codex entry for `get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

`get_sytlesheet_directory_uri` searches first in the child theme directory, and if the file does not exist, or it is not a child theme, then the main theme directory is looked into:

```
echo '<a href="' 
    . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() 
    . '/logout.php" class="linkit">LOGOUT</a>'
    . '<div class="para">Temporary giving up super power.</div>';
```